# Non Blocking assignments in Verilog

Tags: verilog, nonblocking

I was creating a TESTBENCH for a simple XOR gate.I used non blocking statements inside test bench.I was expecting a parallel execution but I ended up with a sequential one.I am attaching the code and outputs below.What may be the problem?

```
module test_xor_tb;
  wire y;
  reg a,b;
  test_xor x1(y,a,b);
  initial begin
    a<=0;b<=0;
    #10 a<=1;
    #10 b<=1;
    #25 b<=0;
    #35 a<=0;
  end
  initial
  $monitor("AT TIME %t,a=%b,b=%b,Y=%b",$time,a,b,y);
endmodule
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module test_xor(y,a,b);
  input a,b;
  output y;
  assign y=a^b;
endmodule
```

the output i got is given below

```
# AT TIME  0,a=0,b=0,Y=0
# AT TIME 10,a=1,b=0,Y=1
# AT TIME 20,a=1,b=1,Y=0
# AT TIME 45,a=1,b=0,Y=1
# AT TIME 80,a=0,b=0,Y=0
```

my expected output was

```
# AT TIME  0,a=0,b=0,Y=0
# AT TIME 10,a=1,b=0,Y=1
# AT TIME 10,a=1,b=1,Y=0
# AT TIME 25,a=1,b=0,Y=1
# AT TIME 35,a=0,b=0,Y=0
```

so why does the nonblocking assignment executing in sequential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#10 a<=1;` is equivalent to `#10; a<=1;` and `#10;` is a blocking statement. To make parallel you need non-blocking delay `a<= #10 1;`

```
initial begin
  a<=0;b<=0;
  a<= #10 1;
  b<= #10 1;
  b<= #25 0;
  a<= #35 0;
end
```

Alternatively, you can put at the assignments in a fork-join.

```
initial begin
  fork
    a<=0;b<=0;
    #10 a<=1;
    #10 b<=1;
    #25 b<=0;
    #35 a<=0;
  join
end
```

I'd recommend the non-blocking delay over the fork-join approach, but both will work.